# How to set the width and height of the drawableleft in styles.xml?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="windowTitleBackgroundStyle">  
        <item name="android:background">#A4D05F</item>                
      </style>
      <style name="windowTitleStyle">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/smartlogo</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#C6C09C</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
      </style>
```

I am customizing my titlebar in android using eclipse ide. I can also see my image that is being set by the drawableleft, however it is too big.  Do you know how to set the width and size of the drawableleft?

Answer (score 0):

if API level 23 and higher you can change like this

```
<item
 name="android:drawableLeft"
 android:drawable="@drawable/smartlogo"
 android:height="24dp"
 android:width="24dp"/>
```

Comment: it is giving me an error: "a 'name' attribute is required for <item>" since it is inside in my style

Comment: @picolo is the drawable is an xml file?

Comment: it is, i just scaled my image in photoshop to make it smaller. but thanks for the help :)

Comment: i upvoted you and the other comment, it is just not reflecting because of my reputation

Answer (score 0):

you can use a xml-drawable, that you can customise as you wish.

You can find [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html#shape-drawables) some examples and a lot others on net.

Alternatively, you can also create a simple XML, containing a view, image etc, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
      android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:height="@dimen/icon_size"
      />

</layer-list >
```

,and use this as your drawableLeft.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i created an xml for the code you posted. I named it as customlogo.xml. How to call it in my drawableleft? sorry for my noob question i am new to eclipse *sobs*

Comment: 1 - to get rid of the error: you should add your new file in the drawable folder.

Comment: 2 - <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/customlogo.xml</item>
It's as simple as that.

Comment: i have created it inside drawable-hdpi. But when i call it  using "<item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/customlogo.xml</item>" it says it doesnt exist that's why i remove.xml and then when i run it, the logo is still big